# validate the character count of comma separated words in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to validate the value which is entered on a text area, whether the user have entered the valid ten digit number within the comma separated values like

> 9876543210,98766543211,98766543212

if the users entered more than or less than 10 digits of number have to alert some error.

so far i have tried something like

```
$("#myMso").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().replace(" ", "");
    var word = value.split(",");

    var lengths = words.map(function(word) {
        if(lengths != 10){
            alert("Hey! some of the contact number you have entered is not valid");
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: don't know the correct way to count the comma separated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
   $("#myMso").keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var word = value.split(",");
        $.each(word,function (key,value) {
            if(value.length != 10){
                alert("Hey! some of the contact number you have entered is not valid");
            }

        });
     });
```

**Modification** for **on-change** event:-

```
 $("#myMso").on('change',function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var word = value.split(",");
            $.each(word,function (key,value) {
                if(value.length != 10){
                    alert("Hey! some of the contact number you have entered is not valid");
                }

            });
         });
```

Comment: this too  not working cant  type a number shows alert every time when i press a key because its validating every time whether it is greater than 10

Comment: As you write your code with event of** `keyup`** that's why its alerting

Answer (score 1):

You have misused map function.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

Should be something like:

```
var lengths = words.map(function(word) {
  // map should return your mapping value.
  return word.length;
})

if (lengths.length > 0) {
  alert("Hey! " + lengths.length + " contact numbers are wrong")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search you text using regex:-

**/^\d{10}(,\d{10})*$/g**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will work for you

```js
$("#myMso").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    checkNumbers(value)
});

function checkNumbers (d) {
    let numbers = d.split(',');
    numbers.forEach((number, i) => {
        number.length < 10 && alert('Incorrect Number' + number);
    });   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: not working cant even type a number shows alert every time when i press a key because its validating every time whether it is greater than 10

Comment: @Error404 you should use check the number on change.. Try your code use on change.